# Change "The selected product combination is currently unavailable" text in BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I'm looking to change the content of the .OutOfStockMessage div in BigCommerce. This div contains the text "The selected product combination is currently unavailable" and appears when an out-of-stock product option is selected. I can change the text via JS, but when a product option is selected, this text is re-built. I cannot find the function or trigger which causes this div to be modified/shown, otherwise I could piggy-back onto it to change the text back. This text is also not globally modifiable from the control panel.

I can set custom text, but only as part of a "Rule" on the Option Set, which won't show up based on Inventory Level.

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is called %%LNG_VariationSoldOutMessage%% and it is located at Snippets/ProductAddToCart.html

**However,** there is a bug still in Bigcommerce (no surprises there) that means removing the variable does not actually take effect.

So either use JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
$('.OutOfStockMessage:contains("combination")').text("This color is currently out of stock" );
})
</script>
```

Or, if you go on to Design Mode and go to the product page which displays the text, you can edit the text directly there and it will take effect.

Comment: The ajaxSuccess trigger works alright, though the original text does flash in. I'm not 100% clear on what you mean about Design Mode. I cannot access the LNG variables from there, and as you mentioned, even overwriting/removing the variable from the template/panel/snippet doesn't really work.

Comment: @ench Go to "Design" in the top right of Admin. Click on "More" and then "Design Mode" and finally "Open My Store in Design Mode". Navigate to the page in question and find the out of stock message on your product page. If you click on the text you wish to amend, you can directly amend the message as a workaround.

Comment: The link you posted links to an "Authorization Required" page. Looks like it isn't public.

Comment: @ench Seems like they have removed the article as I cannot access it either. Try this cached page: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JpWlBEHhHaQJ:https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/890/How%2Bdo%2BI%2Benable%2BDesign%2BMode%253F+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Comment: No luck there either.

Answer (score 1):

Still can't leave comments but I wanted to provide a link for how to access the BigCommerce Design mode.  This -- [https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/890/How+do+I+enable+Design+Mode%3F](http://web.archive.org/web/20130604173721/https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/890/How+do+I+enable+Design+Mode%3F) -- is a link to an archive on the WayBack Machine of that BC article from June 4th, 2013.